# Detect Display button doesn't appear

Tags: display, usb, monterey

I am running the newest version of Monterey on my Macbook Air 2020 with M1 chip and I can't get the Detect Display button to appear (I am having issue connecting my LG 27UN850 through USB Type C). I followed [this tutorial](https://www.lifewire.com/fix-external-display-not-detected-on-mac-5096070#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20System%20Preferences%20%3E%20Displays,update%20adapter%20software%20if%20applicable.) and the button just doesn't appear. Does anybody know how to solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of macOS 12, up to 12.2, you have to have a secondary display attached and detected already to get access to the **Detect displays** button.  If you have a secondary display, you can hold the <kbd>Opt</kbd> and **Night Shift...** will change to **Detect Displays**.  **Night Shift** will not change with the <kbd>Opt</kbd> if there is only the primary display already detected.

Indeed the ramifications of this are that if you are trying to get it to detect a secondary display but having trouble, you don't get access to the **Detect Displays** feature.  This seems like madness to me, but I have a workaround.

Find a third display (yes I apologize), and hook that one up.  If it is detected then you can press <kbd>Opt</kbd> to get access to the **Detect Displays** button, press it, and it will likely detect the original display you were having trouble with.

I just used this procedure to make a USB-C connected display become detected by hooking up a third HDMI display that was detected and then disconnecting the HDMI display.

I have subsequently disconnected and reconnected the USB-C monitor and had it detected, so with any luck, this will be a rarely required workaround.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response. Having to have a secondary display detected to be able to show the **Detect Displays** button doesn't seem to be the smartest design decision.